# Add/remove some text to div after radiobox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, addclass

I have several radio and checkboxes for displaying some divs. I need to display separate div which show text(e.g. name of author) after clicking on radiobox and also add some text to previous text after clicking on checkboxes. Is it possible to create something like this with the help of css/javascript ? Any advice ? I think that I need to add/remove classes with "content:"bla bla"" in css.

Comment: `Is it possible to create something like this with the help of css/javascript?` yes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS solution**
To change the value (or to be specific, the :after content) you do **not** need any JavaScript!
You only need the `:checked` and the opposite `:not(:checked)`. Via the `label data-attributes` you can handel the text for each state and button.

```css
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after{
 content:attr(data-notchecked);
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after{
 content:attr(data-checked);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"><label data-checked="checked Radio 1" data-notchecked="not checked Radio 1" for="radio1"></label><br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"><label data-checked="checked Radio 2" data-notchecked="not checked Radio 2" for="radio2"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with pure JavaScript functions:

```
// assign function to onclick property of checkbox
document.getElementById('TestCheckbox').onclick = function() {
    // access properties using this keyword
    if ( this.checked ) {
        // if checked ...
        alert( this.value );
    } else {
        // if not checked ...
    }
};
```

But I think JQuery or AngularJS give you better and simpler solutions for this:

Example for JQuery:

```
if(document.getElementById('TestCheckbox').checked)
    $("#TestDiv").show();  // Show||hide div or anything else
  else
    $("#TestDiv").hide(); // Show||hide div or anything else
```

you can use class's Instead of IDs, to reduce your codes.
Also I agree with Luca Jung method.